# cross table and calculated field

Tags: many-to-many, powerpivot, calculated-columns

I'm just starting using Powerpivot, and my first application raised some harder problems that I would have thought... Here is my problem:

I have 3 tables: factRepairs; factCorss; dimSpares

factRepairs:

[image]

factCross

[image]

dimSpares

[image]

factRepairs is linked to factCross by a relationship between the Repair column, and factCross is linked to dimSpares through Spare ID <->Spare

I want to add a calculated column (or measure, not sure at this stage) to give the cost of spares used for one repair.

I've been looking for solution for a while but I didn't manage to figure it out...
If someone can guide me through a formula to do this it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right to think that many-to-many is an non-trivial problem in PowerPivot!

The good news is that this is probably more of a data structure issue than a pure underlying many to many situation and can be easily solved with a calculated column on the `factCross` table. This works a bit like a SUMIF in excel and doesn't require a relationship:

```
 = CALCULATE(SUM(dimSpares[price]), 
       FILTER(dimSpares, 
              dimSpares[id] = EARLIER([spare id])
              )
             )
```

You can then write a measure/calculated field to sum the cost and if you create a relationship between `factRepairs` and `factCross` you should be in business.

If you are looking for a more sophisticated way to deal with these problems then try [the Many to Many revolution](http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/many2many/) but honestly that's about as complex as DAX gets so I would concentrate on simpler stuff :-)

Comment: Works like a charm! thanks a lot for your help! I do have another issue that has not been helping me so far: the autocomplete of my DAX expressions mention a semicon instead of a comma, and the strange thing is if I use comas the autocomplete works but the expression thoughs a syntaxe error. If I use semicons the autocomplete doesn't work but the expression works fine... Any idea why (i had to change your commas to semicon to make it work)

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Suspect that the autocomplete has never been adjusted for locales where you use semi colon instead of comma.